# How is Cloud Functions for Firebase memory usage calculated for static variables?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my index.js file, before I declare the exported functions I have a preprocessing step where I read some files from the cloud and build a couple of large hashmaps. The exported cloud functions use these hashmaps.

Do these hashmaps persist in the memory of the machine even when the function isn't called, and count toward the gb-seconds limitations?

Answer (score 1):

GB-seconds are only billed while a function is running on an allocated instance.  When there is no function running, there is no billing, but you cannot be certain that any state from a previous run will be available.

Comment: Thanks. After initial startup the hashmaps won't be modified. The functions only read from them; they don't write to them. In that case can I be certain they will always be able to read that hashmap? Is there some sort of startup overhead in this case? Will some unlucky user trigger an entire startup sequence that could take minutes before getting a response?

Comment: If there is any chance that a function could be executed before your maps are fully built, that sounds like a potential problem.  Also, you might be starving memory from other functions as they need to run.  Anyway, you shouldn't be charged if there are no functions running at any given moment.